# Split custom fields in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource, azure-log-analytics, azure-oms

I am getting data from **Azure Log Analytics** to **Power BI** using the **M Language Query** generated directly from the OMS Portal. The issue that, the custom columns are getting loaded into the Power BI in a single column in the below format with the column name as `"CustomEventDimensions"`:

```
"Custom_Column_1":"Value_1"
"Custom_Column_2":"Value_2"
"Custom_Column_3":"Value_3"
"Custom_Column_4":"Value_4"
```

I want this to be split into different columns with the `Custom_column_n` as the column name and the `Value_n` as the value.

Is it possible to modify the M query to get the data according to my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a table like this:

[image: Start]

First, split it into two columns in the query editor using Split Column > By Delimiter under the Transform tab.

[image: Split]

Next, pivot the first column (Transform > Pivot Column) using the second as the Values Column. Make sure to choose Don't Aggregate under the Advanced options.

[image: Pivot]